# Error while load spark job result to BigQuery using apache airflow

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I want to load my spark job result in a airflow task which is a json file with a spark format like part-xxxxxxx.json

Here is my code,

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta , date 

from airflow import models,DAG 

from airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator import DataprocClusterCreateOperator,DataProcPySparkOperator,DataprocClusterDeleteOperator

from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator

from airflow.operators import BashOperator 

from airflow.models import *

from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule


current_date = str(date.today())

BUCKET = "gs://bigdata-etl-2_flights"

PROJECT_ID = "bigdata-etl-2"

PYSPARK_JOB = BUCKET + "/spark-job/spark-etl-job-1.py"

DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS = {
    'owner':"airflow",
    'depends_on_past' : False,
    "start_date":datetime.utcnow(),
    "email_on_failure":False,
    "email_on_retry":False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay":timedelta(minutes=5),
    "project_id":PROJECT_ID,
    "scheduled_interval":"0 5 * * *"
}

with DAG("flights_etl_testing",default_args=DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS) as dag : 

    create_cluster = DataprocClusterCreateOperator(

        task_id ="create_dataproc_cluster",
        cluster_name="ephemeral-spark-cluster-{{ds_nodash}}",
        master_machine_type="n1-standard-1",
        worker_machine_type="n1-standard-2",
        num_workers=2,
        region="asia-east1",
        zone ="asia-east1-a"
    )

    submit_pyspark = DataProcPySparkOperator(
        task_id = "run_pyspark_etl",
        main = PYSPARK_JOB,
        cluster_name="ephemeral-spark-cluster-{{ds_nodash}}",
        region="asia-east1"
    )

    bq_load_delays_by_distance = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(

        task_id = "bq_load_avg_delays_by_distance",
        bucket=BUCKET,
        source_objects=["flights_data_output/"+current_date+"_distance_category/*.json"],
        destination_project_dataset_table= f'{PROJECT_ID}:data_flights.avg_delays_by_distance',
        autodetect = True,
        source_format="NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        skip_leading_rows=0,
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        max_bad_records=0,
    )

    bq_load_delays_by_flight_nums = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(

        task_id = "bq_load_delays_by_flight_nums",
        bucket=BUCKET,
        source_objects=["flights_data_output/"+current_date+"_flight_nums/*.json"],
        destination_project_dataset_table=f'{PROJECT_ID}:data_flights.avg_delays_by_flight_nums',
        autodetect = True,
        source_format="NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        skip_leading_rows=0,
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        max_bad_records=0,
    )

    delete_cluster = DataprocClusterDeleteOperator(

        task_id ="delete_dataproc_cluster",
        cluster_name="ephemeral-spark-cluster-{{ds_nodash}}",
        region="asia-east1",
        trigger_rule = TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
    )

    delete_tranformed_files = BashOperator(
        task_id = "delete_tranformed_files",
        bash_command = "gsutil -m rm -r " +BUCKET + "/flights_data_output/*"
    )

    create_cluster.dag = dag

    create_cluster.set_downstream(submit_pyspark)

    submit_pyspark.set_downstream(bq_load_delays_by_distance)

    bq_load_delays_by_distance.set_downstream(bq_load_delays_by_flight_nums)

    bq_load_delays_by_flight_nums.set_downstream(delete_cluster)
    
    delete_cluster.set_downstream(delete_tranformed_files)
```

Task 1 = create_cluster completed
Task 2 = submit spark job completed

but in task 3 i got and error like this:

```
*** Reading remote log from gs://asia-east2-airflow-flight-j-442c4eb8-bucket/logs/flights_etl_testing/bq_load_avg_delays_by_distance/2021-03-20T17:25:55.218034+00:00/2.log.
[2021-03-20 17:36:06,559] {taskinstance.py:671} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: flights_etl_testing.bq_load_avg_delays_by_distance 2021-03-20T17:25:55.218034+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-03-20 17:36:06,945] {taskinstance.py:671} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: flights_etl_testing.bq_load_avg_delays_by_distance 2021-03-20T17:25:55.218034+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-03-20 17:36:06,946] {taskinstance.py:881} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-03-20 17:36:06,946] {taskinstance.py:882} INFO - Starting attempt 2 of 2
[2021-03-20 17:36:06,946] {taskinstance.py:883} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-03-20 17:36:06,980] {taskinstance.py:902} INFO - Executing <Task(GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator): bq_load_avg_delays_by_distance> on 2021-03-20T17:25:55.218034+00:00
[2021-03-20 17:36:06,985] {standard_task_runner.py:54} INFO - Started process 3724 to run task
[2021-03-20 17:36:07,074] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'flights_etl_testing', 'bq_load_avg_delays_by_distance', '2021-03-20T17:25:55.218034+00:00', '--job_id', '109', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/spark-bq-dag.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpnsb9j5cm']
[2021-03-20 17:36:07,082] {standard_task_runner.py:78} INFO - Job 109: Subtask bq_load_avg_delays_by_distance
[2021-03-20 17:36:07,597] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: flights_etl_testing.bq_load_avg_delays_by_distance 2021-03-20T17:25:55.218034+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-worker-c5555fddc-vmtwq
[2021-03-20 17:36:08,126] {gcp_api_base_hook.py:145} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.@-@{"workflow": "flights_etl_testing", "task-id": "bq_load_avg_delays_by_distance", "execution-date": "2021-03-20T17:25:55.218034+00:00"}
[2021-03-20 17:36:08,505] {taskinstance.py:1152} ERROR - <HttpError 400 when requesting https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/bigdata-etl-2/jobs?alt=json returned "Source URI must be a Google Cloud Storage location: gs://gs://bigdata-etl-2_flights/flights_data_output/2021-03-20_distance_category/*.json". Details: "Source URI must be a Google Cloud Storage location: gs://gs://bigdata-etl-2_flights/flights_data_output/2021-03-20_distance_category/*.json">
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 985, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_bq.py", line 288, in execut
    encryption_configuration=self.encryption_configuration
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 1302, in run_loa
    return self.run_with_configuration(configuration
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 1323, in run_with_configuratio
    .execute(num_retries=self.num_retries
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrappe
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 915, in execut
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/bigdata-etl-2/jobs?alt=json returned "Source URI must be a Google Cloud Storage location: gs://gs://bigdata-etl-2_flights/flights_data_output/2021-03-20_distance_category/*.json". Details: "Source URI must be a Google Cloud Storage location: gs://gs://bigdata-etl-2_flights/flights_data_output/2021-03-20_distance_category/*.json"
[2021-03-20 17:36:08,509] {taskinstance.py:1196} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=flights_etl_testing, task_id=bq_load_avg_delays_by_distance, execution_date=20210320T172555, start_date=20210320T173606, end_date=20210320T173608
[2021-03-20 17:36:12,827] {local_task_job.py:102} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

I am expecting that task 3 will create a bigquery table as avg_delays_by_distance and avg_delays_by_flight_nums

please kindly to help and explain why i got an error like that while running task 3

Comment: Did you even read the error message? It tells you exactly what went wrong. The bucket name is wrong. No need for `gs://`

Comment: so, did you mean that should i write the bucket parameter like this bucket='bigdata-etl-2_flights'? based on this case my bucket is bigdata-etl-2_flights